# How to convert Microsoft Doc into PDF file using python

Tags: python, plugins, pdf-generation, doc

I am trying to convert Microsoft Docx into PDF file and using this python script

````
import os
import win32com. client
#pip install pywin32

wdFormatPDF = 17
in_file = "in_file/path/Input.docx"
out_file = "out_file/path/output.pdf"

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat = wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()``

But I got this error

```Encoding, InsertLineBreaks, AllowSubstitutions, LineEnding, AddBiDiMarks
pywintypes.com_error: (-214738676867, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\WDMAIN11.CHM', 587257, -214687359843090), None)`

And I also tried another plugin "from docx2pdf import convert" But the same error is coming. So plz suggest how to solve my problem.
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import win32com.client as win32
from os import path
word = win32.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
in_file = path.abspath('c:\\sample.docx')
out_file = path.abspath('c:\\sample.pdf')
# just one argument here
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
# was: 'new_file'
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=17)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @daredevil7, When I used your code the same error `Encoding, InsertLineBreaks, AllowSubstitutions, LineEnding, AddBiDiMarks
pywintypes.com_error: (-214738676867, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\WDMAIN11.CHM', 587257, -214687359843090), None)`  is coming.